# Removing handle image from jquery UI resizable element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

How can I remove the default `southeast (se)` handle **image** of the resizable element and add my own image?

Comment: simply override the classes. These are the classes that are applied by default: `ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options:

1. You can override `ui-resizable-handle` or `ui-resizable-se` as mentioned [on the jQuery site](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Resizable) at the very bottom.
2. You can alter the image file "ui-icons_222222_256x240.png", an example of which is hosted [here, by Google](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/images/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png).

Answer (score 13):

i always do this in my .css file

```
.ui-dialog .ui-resizable-se {
    background-image: url("");
}
```

and it works all the time :)

Comment: For me in version v1.11.4 it is: `.ui-icon { background-image: url("") !important; }`

Answer (score 3):

You can also specify which handles you want in resizable(), e.g for just the "e" handle

```
$("#id").resizable({
    handles: "e"
});
```

http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/#option-handles

Answer (score 3):

You can also work this out at 'create' option:

```
$('#element').resizable({
   create: function(event, ui) {
     $('.ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se').remove();
   }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

inside the div with class `ui-resizable`, you need to replace the background image for the div with class `ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se`

You can do something like:

```
$(".ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se").css("background-image", "url(someImage.png)")
```

Answer (score 0):

The instructions in this post worked for me:

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-to-make-the-se-grip-handle-larger-for-a-jquery-ui-resizeable

Use this css:

```
.ui-widget-content .ui-icon.ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se {
      width: 32px;
      height: 32px;
      background: url(<insert your image url here>) left top no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will work for you :

```
.ui-resizable-handle { 
    z-index: auto !important;
    background-image: url('');
 }
```

if u need to remove the handle-icon completely just set the background-image to none.

```
.ui-resizable-handle { 
    background-image: none;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se').css("background-image", "url('')");
```

Answer (score -1):

I removed the resize handle permanently altering the css like this:

```
<style>
   .ui-icon, .ui-widget-content .ui-icon
   {
      background-image : none;
   }
</style>
```

It works for me.

Comment: Question is how to change specific icon, in your case you are hiding all ui.icons.