# Hide resize function on print

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a page were users can resize images to make a moodboard. Everything is working except the printing. If they print the moodboard there is a white square where the resizer is. I don't know if css is required.

**How can i hide the resizer when printing on paper?**

At the moment i have no css for the resizer. I am using the [jquery resizer function](http://jqueryui.com/resizable/).

**example**

[image]

Comment: nothing cause i dont know if it is css or jquery i need. and i dont know how to apply css to the resizer thats why i post this question . com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With jQuery, normally you would call `$('#yourId').hide()`. Did that not work?

[Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)

Comment: I only need to hide the button for resizing.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get the problem.

Comment: look at the example there is a white square on the image. i need to hide that white square ( the square is the spot where the resize button was)

Comment: Well, then call `$('#theResizerDivId').hide()` after you're done resizing. I assume you do the resizing with jQuery, right? So in the same function, call that codeline (replace `theResizerDivId` with the actual `id` attribute of the white square)

Comment: Thats what i want to do but i can find theResizerDivId i use the default jquery resizer   http://jqueryui.com/resizable/

Comment: Consider using Firebug (Firefox) Add or the Chrome Developer Tools (Chrome). With it, you can inspect elements and find out the id of HTML elements.

Comment: <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se" style="z-index: 90;"></div>

Comment: Well, `$('.ui-resizable-handle').hide()` should do the trick.

Comment: i have posted it in my document ready but it aint doing a thing

Answer (score 1):

You should add this in header:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="path_to_special_print_css" media="print" />
```

And in this css file add this:

```
#resizeblock {
  visible: hidden;
}
```

Comment: If you would like to format the website secially for printers then use this css code. you can do everything with website.

Comment: Where do i have to make the div resizeblock?

Comment: you have to create new css file, for example: style_printers.css
Then you LINK tag will look that
<link type="text/css" href="style_printers.css" screen="print" />

In this new file you should paste css method for this DIV

Comment: i use the default jquery function  .resizable wich creates the resizer.

Comment: my code in head is <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="print.css">     in print it is     .resizer { display: none; }

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a specific print stylesheet in the `<head>`? Like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="print.css">
```

In `print.css` you can set print-specific properties. So, you can target the resizer and hide it:

```
.resizer { display: none; }
```

(assuming the resizer has a `resizer` class)

Comment: i use the default resize function of jquery. i dont know if the class resizer exist.

Comment: i use a external class like print.css and added you code but it isnt hiding.

Comment: OK, I assume you're using the jQuery UI resizable: http://jqueryui.com/resizable/ - try changing `.resizer` to `.ui-resizable` (this is the class name that gets appended by jQuery UI to the resizable element).

Comment: i tryd  .ui-resizable 
{ 
display: none; 
}  but i cant drag my items anymore

Comment: Did you put that in your print.css file only?

Comment: if i put it on the print.css there are no dropped elements visible on the print page.

Comment: Ah, my apologies - try `.ui-resizable-handle { display: none; }` in the print.css file instead.

Comment: i tryd useing .ui-resizable-handle { display: none; } in both style.css and print.css but it isnt makeing any diffrence its exactly the same as when i leave it. my html element is like  <div class="ui-draggable sleep ui-resizable">

Comment: It would probably help if you post some sample HTML on jsfiddle. I'm assuming the use of the resizable element like this: http://jqueryui.com/resizable/ (if you inspect the resizable element you can see the resizable handle has a class of `.ui-resizable-handle`). Basically, you need to identify the handle and hide that.

Comment: you need to identify the handle and hide that.  that is exactly my question how i can preform that

Comment: You need to inspect the HTML - to do this in Chrome, navigate to your page and press F12 to bring up developer tools. Then, on the "Elements" tab, click the magnifying glass icon. Move your mouse over the handle to see the classes that it has. More here: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/elements

Comment: <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se" style="z-index: 90;"></div>

Comment: Maybe try some of the techniques here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10801676/removing-handle-image-from-jquery-ui-resizable-element - otherwise I'm at a loss! :)

Comment: with inspect element i have found the icon  .ui-icon, .ui-widget-content .ui-icon {
background-image: url(images/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png)/*{iconsContent}*/;
}   but i cant replace it in css !